# Arduino: What is the best way to send and receive data with I2C?

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi, python

I am using I2C to send and receive int values from a RaspberryPi to an Arduino then echoed back to the Pi.

The primary problem I am having is with int values larger than 255.

A secondary problem is when trying to stream values constantly. My goal is to send MouseX,Y coordinates constantly from the Pi to an Arduino. here is my test code showing basic ability to send int values 0-255 from a RPi to an Arduino.

My first question is, should I keep values as ints or convert everything to String BEFORE sending over serial?

My second question is, if keeping as int, what modifications should I make to the following so that values larger than 255 will work?

RPi Python code first.

```
import smbus
import time
# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    # bus.write_byte_data(address, 0, value)
    return -1

def readNumber():
    number = bus.read_byte(address)
    # number = bus.read_byte_data(address, 1)
    return number

while True:
    try:
        var = int(raw_input("Enter 1 - 9: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Could you at least give me an actual number?"
        continue

    writeNumber(var)
    print "RPI: Hi Arduino, I sent you ", var
    # sleep one second
    #time.sleep(1)

    number = readNumber()
    print "Arduino: Hey RPI, I received a digit ", number
    print
```

Arduino code

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04
int number = 0;
int state = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);         // start serial for output
    // initialize i2c as slave
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

    // define callbacks for i2c communication
    Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
    Wire.onRequest(sendData);

    Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}

// callback for received data
void receiveData(int byteCount){

    while(Wire.available()) {
        number = Wire.read();
        if (Wire.available() > 1)  // at least 2 bytes
        {
          number = Wire.read() * 256 + Wire.read();
        }
        Serial.print("data received: ");
        Serial.println(number);
        //sendData();
        if (number == 1){

            if (state == 0){
                digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // set the LED on
                state = 1;
            }
            else{
                digitalWrite(13, LOW); // set the LED off
                state = 0;
            }
         }
     }
}

// callback for sending data
void sendData(){
    Wire.write(number);
}
```

Comment: You need to develop some sort of protocol, then mask and send the appropriate bits.

Comment: Thanks, could you be a bit more specific? 'Some sort of protocol', really unclear what you mean

Comment: You're going to need to look at the Arduino source to determine how the library uses the AVR's USART hardware. I know for a fact that the AtMega328P only has hardware support for an 8bit word, so you may need to see what happens when you try and send an `int` which is *at least* 2 bytes defined by ANSI. It might be that the software implementation takes only the last 8 bits (i.e. simple assignment of your variable to the serial buffer would do this) and transmits; this would explain why you have valid results for [0,255]. Stemming off what eco_bach suggests, you may want to consider sending

Comment: ... an *indicator* byte that tells your software on the other end "the next X bytes are an `int`", or maybe "the next bytes *until* a special character is received represent a character string"; such an implementation is a very simplistic *protocol*.

Comment: You're going to need to transfer more than one byte. Typically, ints are 32-bits, but sometimes 16 is used. You'll have to figure out which you plan to use and transfer either 2 or 4 bytes. I'm not familiar with the wire and smbus libraries, but I think there are two simple approaches to this. The first would be to use multi-byte transactions, in this case the master would expect multiple bytes from the slave per request. The second would be to define multiple addresses two which your arduino would respond each with a designated meaning. There are other approaches as well.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you need to define a small protocol.  An example protocol could be something like the following:

[LENGTH] [INSTR] [DATA] [BCC]

where INSTR would be a command and data some payload associated to that piece of data.  LENGTH_DATA would be the amount of bytes for the packet (including INSTR & BCC) and BCC a kind of checksum of all the packet's data.

If you want a command that turn on/off a led, then you can have this command:

[0x04] [0x01] [LED_STATE] [BCC]

To send mouse data:

[0x07] [0x02] [X_H] [X_L] [Y_H] [H_L] [BCC]

Basically, you can't send anything larger than 8 bit at once with an Arduino, but you may well split your number in smaller chunks.  I don't know much about Arduino code, but the actual implementation could be something like that:

struct
   {
    unsigned long int X;
    unsigned long int Y;
   } mouse;

```
unsigned char buffer[20];
unsigned char bufferIndex=0;

void validatePacket(void)
{
 int i;
 unsigned char bcc=0;

 for(i=0;i<bufferIndex;bcc^=buffer[i++]);
 return ~(bcc+1);
}

void dataReceived(int byteCount)
{
 int i;

 while(Wire.available()>0)
 {
  buffer[bufferIndex++]=Wire.read();
  if(bufferIndex==buffer[0]) // Check if we received "length" bytes.
  {
   if(validatePacket())
   {
    switch(buffer[1])
    {
     case 0x01: // Led toggle command.
      digitalWrite(13,buffer[2]?HIGH:LOW);
     break;
     case 0x02: // Mouse data.
      mouse.X=(unsigned long int)buffer[2]<<8+buffer[3];
      mouse.Y=(unsigned long int)buffer[4]<<8+buffer[5];
     break;
     default: // Unknown command.
      Serial.print("Bad packet");
     break;
    }
   }
   else
   {
    Serial.print("Bad checksum");
   }
   bufferIndex=0;
  }
 }
}
```

Well, something of the like.  The protocol is crappy and not so much bullet-proof (if length is corrupted, you could get your communication channel to stall), but it is an example.  You can modify it as much as you like.  By the way, it is not tested nor compiled so I don't even know if it is valid Arduino code.